# How do websites set a maximum upload limit? Are there ways to bypass it?

Tags: web-services, file-upload

For example: YouTube, before verifying your account, limits the maximum upload size to 15 minutes. How does it measure the size? Is there a way to edit the maximum upload size from your browser, make the site read the file as a 15-minute video though it's more, or is it all done on the server side, so there's no way to edit except from the server itself? This question also applies to other types of data, like text and images.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed server size, say in PHP. It takes the file, looks at it there, and rejects it based on what the file actually is. So no, it can't be bypassed.